# Load data from aws S3 to jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jstree

I have several directories in aws S3 bucket. I need to load the same structure to jsTree (jquery plugin).

The problem I have is to how to identify the parent node of each element as aws S3 (listObjectsV2) identifies each elements as separate objects and not directories.

Here is an example of what it returns

```js
{ Key: 'private/Nifla/2)-M1-Kinematics-of-a-Particle-moving-in-a-Straight-Line-Questions.docx',
0|server  |     LastModified: 2018-09-04T06:24:18.000Z,
0|server  |     ETag: '"c3dbdb890c19ce5e289227e96a702dc8"',
0|server  |     Size: 1230564,
0|server  |     StorageClass: 'STANDARD' },
0|server  |   { Key: 'private/Nifla/2)-M1-Kinematics-of-a-Particle-moving-in-a-Straight-Line.pptx',
0|server  |     LastModified: 2018-09-04T06:16:45.000Z,
0|server  |     ETag: '"84aaa52152fcbc36768fca819e1bf84d"',
0|server  |     Size: 1166244,
0|server  |     StorageClass: 'STANDARD' },
0|server  |   { Key: 'private/Nifla/3)-M1-Dynamics-of-a-Particle-moving-in-a-Straight-Line-Questions.docx',
0|server  |     LastModified: 2018-09-04T06:29:21.000Z,
0|server  |     ETag: '"5d078bebd1edc40e5db9ff5f489df610"',
0|server  |     Size: 2247048,
0|server  |     StorageClass: 'STANDARD' },
0|server  |   { Key: 'private/Nifla/3)-M1-Dynamics-of-a-Particle-moving-in-a-Straight-Line.pptx',
0|server  |     LastModified: 2018-09-04T06:15:49.000Z,
0|server  |     ETag: '"d27ff757a5c6bf05d9e02ec80529dfad"',
0|server  |     Size: 1557098,
0|server  |     StorageClass: 'STANDARD' },
0|server  |   { Key: 'private/Nifla/6)-M1-Vectors-Questions.docx',
0|server  |     LastModified: 2018-07-24T05:44:39.000Z,
0|server  |     ETag: '"1e146a050cc4d4a8fd8919bb4fc0f151"',
0|server  |     Size: 2570995,
0|server  |     StorageClass: 'STANDARD' }
```

Eventhough all these files are under 'private/Nifla' directory, they are separate objects to S3.

Here is how I tried to adjust the structure to fit jsTree.

```js
function s3ToJsTreeJsonConvertor(s3ObjectList){
    var data = []
    var files = s3ObjectList.Contents;
    console.log('----files-----');
    console.log(files);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var Key = files[i].Key
        var filterRegex = new RegExp('(.pdf)');
        var isFolder = filterRegex.test(Key);
        if(!isFolder){
            continue;
        }
        console.log("///////////////",Key);
        var res = Key.split("/");
        console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",res);
        for (var j=0;j< res.length;j++){
            var isFile = false;
            if(j===res.length-1){
                isFile = true;
            }
            if(j===0){
                data.push({ "id" : "node_"+i+"_"+j, "parent" : "#", "text" : res[j],"data":{"key":Key,"isFile":isFile } });
                continue;
            }
            data.push({ "id" : "node_"+i+"_"+j, "parent" : "node_"+i+"_"+(j-1), "text" : res[j],"data":{"key":Key,"isFile":isFile } });
        }
    }
    return data;

}
```

This results in the following structure.

[image: jsTree structure]

Problem is how to identify the parent directory of each file. Can anyone suggest a solution to this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure prefix string in your listObjectsV2 , so that it will return objects beginning with the prefix string. lets say you have content like /bucketName/folder1/file1.txt , If you configure prefix as folder1 , it will return all objects inside folder1 including folder1. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property